# Python: how to use list as source of selection for user input?

Tags: python, input, multiple-choice

Can anyone check this code and let me know what is wrong?

```
input_list = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
P1 = input("Select the input: ", input_list[0], input_list[1], input_list[2])
print (P1)
```

Answer (score 16):

With python's `raw_input` it is not possible to give a preselected list to the user to choose from. With `raw_input` we collect raw strings.

**update**: a nice solution is to use the new pick library: https://github.com/wong2/pick It provides a small curses interface to pick our choice from a given list. Get it with `pip install pick`. (update: multi-select: yes)

**update 2**: and yet another python lib ! https://curses-menu.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#getting-a-selection (no multi-select)

There's a tiny and unmaintained library made for that purpose, [picker](http://pp19dd.com/2013/11/simple-python-list-picker-using-curses/) (multi-select: yes).

The simplest solution I'm thinking of is to use shell tools:

- `dialog` is what distros like Debian use to present UIs in the console,
- [selecta](https://github.com/garybernhardt/selecta) is a fuzzy text selector for the shell, so it fits exactly our needs, except it is a ruby tool,
- zenity (and [yad-dialog](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yad-dialog/)) make it very easy to build simple windows (we exit the terminal). I can display a list with this:

  ```
  zenity --list --text="a title" --column="first column" "first choice" "second choice"
  ```

  We can also select multiple choices.
- if we exit the console, we can use more complete GUI tools like gooey (it turns a python script with command line arguments into a GUI) or even Flexxx [and others](https://github.com/vinta/awesome-python#gui), but that's another work.

Comment: A lib to install with `npm`, to select one or multiple items: https://github.com/ruyadorno/ipt

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the documentation of the `input` function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input

`input` presents a prompt and evaluates the data input by the user as if it were a Python expression. If you just want to gather data input by the user, use `raw_input` instead. You'll need to implement custom logic to make sure the user's input matches with something in your list.