# how to search the result from a string input in a list

Tags: python, string, list, if-statement, string-search

Hi i need to make a project for school where people can insert a review but before the review is posted on twitter it is going to be placed in a database. before it is going to be posted in twitter a moderator needs to check every review to see if there are no swear words etc. i wanted to make a small code in python where the moderator can insert which review he wants to see

i written in python

```
show_review = str(input("which reviews do you want to check: "))
```

and i want python to search the result of that question in the list

```
reviews_of_today = [review1, review2, review3, review4, review5, review6, review7, review8, review9, review10]
```

what code do i need to use or write to perform my needs?

```
review1 = ("Reizen ging soepel")
review2 = ("Het reizen was erg tof")
review3 = ("Kanker NS")
review4 = ("Het ging simpel")
review5 = ("Goede regels voor corona")
review6 = ("Trein kwam eindelijk een keer optijd")
review7 = ("NS komt altijd telaat! Tyfus zooi!")
review8 = ("Kut NS weer vertraging")
review9 = ("Volgende keer neem ik de taxi, sjonge jonge jonge altijd weer het zelfde probleem met NS")
review10 = ("NS Altijd goede ervaring mee gehad")


reviews_of_today = [review1, review2, review3, review4, review5, review6, review7, review8, review9, review10]


#reviews_of_today_no_duplicates = list(dict.fromkeys(reviews_of_today))
# result = []

show_review = str(input("which reviews do you want to check: "))

moderator_want_to_see_review = (show_review)

if moderator_want_to_see_review in show_review:
    print()
```

Comment: please have a look at the below related post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28425204/python-how-to-use-list-as-source-of-selection-for-user-input

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
reviews = ['Reizen ging soepel',
           'Het reizen was erg tof',
           'Kanker NS',
           'Het ging simpel',
           'Goede regels voor corona',
           'Trein kwam eindelijk een keer optijd',
           'NS komt altijd telaat! Tyfus zooi!',
           'Kut NS weer vertraging',
           'Volgende keer neem ik de taxi, sjonge jonge jonge altijd weer het zelfde probleem met NS',
           'NS Altijd goede ervaring mee gehad']

review_id = int(input('which reviews do you want to check: ')) - 1

print(reviews[review_id])
```

Example:

```
which reviews do you want to check: 5
Goede regels voor corona
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply the reviews must stay in strings and we need to read it from the list

Comment: I don't understand `the reviews must stay in strings` - can you show an example of it?

Comment: i completed it look underneath

Answer (score 0):

Alderveren i completed it as following

```
reviews = {
    "review1"   :     "Reizen ging soepel",
    "review2"   :     "Het reizen was erg tof",
    "review3"   :     "Kanker NS",
    "review4"   :     "Het ging simpel",
    "review5"   :     "Goede regels voor corona",
    "review6"   :     "Trein kwam eindelijk een keer optijd",
    "review7"   :     "NS komt altijd telaat! Tyfus zooi!",
    "review8"   :     "Kut NS weer vertraging",
    "review9"   :     "Volgende keer neem ik de taxi, sjonge jonge jonge altijd weer het zelfde probleem met NS",
    "review10"  :     "NS Altijd goede ervaring mee gehad",
}

reaction_moderator = input("Which reviews do you want to check: ").lower()

print(reviews[reaction_moderator])

reaction_moderator = input('Accept or Reject? ').lower()

accept = "accept"
reject = "reject"

x = [accept]
z = [reject]

if reaction_moderator in x:
    print("Accepted")

elif reaction_moderator in z:
    print("Rejected")

else:
    print("Error 404")
```